# Symfony on Apache permission issues

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu, permissions

I have made a lot of Symfony apps that work in production, but recently tried deploying one to Ubuntu 16 for the first time. var/logs/prod.log shows errors about not being able to find classes, so of course the app won't run.

I can "fix" this with chmod 777 /var/www/ -R, and everything starts working. Surely that's not safe... How can I fix this the right way?

Note: I am currently not logged in as a user but as root.

*EDIT
The app will not run after chmod 777 /var/www/var -R to change permissions for chache and logs, but only if I change the permissions for all the folders of the entire app.

Answer (score 2):

You might try locating folders/files which are the problem and change ownership to `www-data` which is actually used by Apache.

For a whole directory with files recursively:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data [folder_path_and_name]
```

For a specific file:

```
chown www-data:www-data [file_path_and_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has a section in the [documentation for file permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html)

Mainly you need to adjust the apache user permissions for logging, and as root you can easily do that.
Just remember to ignore the logs + cache if you're using source control such as Github.